# illustrator join two objects into one

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

I want to merge two objects and select only the outside path, I don't want the path inside. How do I do this in Illustrator ?

[image: paths]

Answer (score 2):

Select both paths and in Pathfinder press Unite or Merge button. If the colors of the both objects are similar the results of both these operations are the same. If the colors are different, use Unite operation.

Remember, that unit operation recolors all objects to the color of uppermost object.

Answer (score 0):

`Object > Group` will not alter the objects, unlike Pathfinder operations, but will make the two object act as if they are one object.

Comment: Is there way to create an outline of a group? (I deleted from my answer info about groupping coz didnt understand what the aurhor finally wanted to do)